# Adding custom model metadata provider in asp.net web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

Im trying to register a custom model metadata provider in web api 2.
as this [page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api#services) says i should call

```
config.Services.Add(typeof (ModelMetadataProvider), new CustomModelMetadataProvider());
```

but with this i get following error

> The service type ModelMetadataProvider is not supported.
>   Parameter name: serviceType

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but the DefaultServices collection attached to HttpConfiguration internally has two sets of services attached to it, Multiple (which can have multiple implementations registered) and Single (which can only have a single implementation).

ModelMetadataProvider is a service type that can only have a single implementation registered. Calling Add tries to add an additional implementation to that already there, so call Replace instead.

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(ModelMetadataProvider), new CustomModelMetadataProvider());
```

Comment: Or `services.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IModelMetadataProvider), typeof(CustomModelMetadataProvider), ServiceLifetime.Singleton))`

Answer (score 0):

You can override the ModelDataProvider by registering your replacement service in your dependency resolver container. Web API will then use this instead of the default DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider.

However, you are limited in what you can do in a custom metadata provider. Caching of metadata is important for performance in most applications and the base implementation of ModelMetadata has marked members, which are vital to caching, as INTERNAL. It appears that Microsoft do not intend this functionality to be customised.